# Android: Listview change Image - with Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to make a Image in a ListView change on click, it does change, but when i scroll down and than back up the image change to the default one. my CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song> {

    public ArrayList<Song> mlist;
    public ArrayList<Song> original_mlist;
    public Context context;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageView ivFav;
    TextView tvArtist;
    TextView tvSongName;
    TextView tvDate;
    DBTools dbTools;
    String tvDate_from_list;
    String tvArtist_from_list;
    String tvSongName_from_list;
    String backgroundImageName;
    ImageView ivFavInside;
    String ImageTagText="";

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Song> mlist) {
        super(context, resource);
        dbTools = new DBTools(context);
        this.mlist = mlist;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition(Song item) {
        return super.getPosition(item);
    }

    @Override
    public Song getItem(int position) {
        return mlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playlist_item_layout, null);
        tvArtist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvArtist);
        tvSongName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSongName);
        tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        ivFav = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivFav);

        tvArtist_from_list = mlist.get(position).getSingerName();
        tvSongName_from_list = mlist.get(position).getSongName();
        tvDate_from_list = mlist.get(position).getDate();

        tvArtist_from_list = tvArtist_from_list.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|' ')", "");
        tvSongName_from_list = tvSongName_from_list.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|' ')", "");
        tvDate_from_list = tvDate_from_list.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|' ')", "");

        tvArtist.setText(tvArtist_from_list);
        tvSongName.setText(tvSongName_from_list);
        tvDate.setText(tvDate_from_list);

        try {
            Cursor c = dbTools.getAllRowsByQuery("SELECT * FROM favs WHERE singerName='" + tvArtist_from_list + "' AND songName='" + tvSongName_from_list + "'");
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                ivFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.plank4);
                ivFav.setTag("full");
            } else {
                ivFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.plank4_empty);
                ivFav.setTag("");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            alert(e.toString());

        }

        ivFav.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   

                // ------------------------------------
                // Heart Icon(only) - Show / Hide
                // ------------------------------------
                ivFavInside = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivFav);
                String backgroundImageName = ivFavInside.getTag().toString();
                if (backgroundImageName == null || backgroundImageName == "") {
                    ivFavInside.setImageResource(R.drawable.plank4);
                    ivFavInside.setTag("full");
                } else {
                    ivFavInside.setImageResource(R.drawable.plank4_empty);
                    ivFavInside.setTag("");
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }
}
```

tryed this (on the GetView - after I set my ivFav):

```
ImageTagText = ivFav.getTag().toString();
        if (ImageTagText != null || ImageTagText != "") {
            ivFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.plank4);
        }
```

but It's cruising - with this error message:

```
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at com.manishma.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:92)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2210)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2045)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14255)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4413)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14255)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4413)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:446)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14255)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4413)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14255)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4413)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:446)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14255)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4413)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1998)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1812)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1050)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4560)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5171)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
03-28 00:14:39.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11363):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

how I can make it stay on the changed image ?

Comment: Use a Flag? Use an array to store flag values for each row?

Comment: Its because everytime the view in the listview is visible, the custom adapter calls "getView", so whatever image you are setting in the adapter for the view at particular position is shown in the list.